# Swift UIKeyboard issue in iOS 8.3 for iPhone 4s

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, xcode6

I just installed iOS 8.3 on my iPhone 4s for testing my program. The swipe doesn't work on swift keyboard even turning on full access in the settings. Does we have to enable something from UITextfield  to enable swipe for a specific input type.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What exactly is `swipe doesn't work on swift keyboard`?